# Ember-cli bootstrap-sass doesn't compile correctly.

Tags: ember-cli, bootstrap-sass

ember version: 0.2.3
node: 0.12.2
npm: 2.7.6

I ran the commands 
`ember new app`
`cd app`
`npm install --save-dev ember-cli-bootstrap-sass` 
`mv app/styles/app.css app/styles/app.scss`
add the line `@import: 'bootstrap';`
run
`ember serve`
When the app compiles, I get `dist/assets/app.scss` (rather than app.css) and all it contains is `@import: 'bootstrap';`. 
What am I missing?

`"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-sass": "^0.2.11",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.8",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.4",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.10",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2"`

Answer (score 2):

The package provides Bootstrap in SASS format. Your app doesn't have a SASS preprocessor, you must add that too.

You could use [ember-cli-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-sass), I'm sure there are other alternatives.